# Is it possible to add images to existing node or node group?

Tags: python, shader-nodes, pynodes

Is it possible to add images or interactive graphs like color ramp or RGB curves to UI of existing node or node group?

example:
[image: example of how it should look like]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Short answer is you can't unless you're willing to modify the source code.